# Why we need additional () in std::hash<sometype>()(somevalue)?

Tags: c++, c++11, hash

I want to create an hash for a custom type and I've seen that I must write something like

```
template <>
struct hash<MyClass>
{
  std::size_t operator()(const MyClass& key) const
  {
    return std::hash<int>()(key.getID());
  }
};
```

The code works but I don't understant why I must write

```
std::hash<int>()(key.getID());
```

instead of

```
std::hash<int>(key.getID());
```

What's the meaning of the middle `()` operator? I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and I've tried to see the `std::hash` source code, but I'm not good enough to understant it well...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`std::hash<int>` is a type. `std::hash<int>()` is an object of that type. `std::hash<int>()(key.getID());` calls `operator()` on that object.

It might be easier to understand if the object is not temporary:

```
std::hash<int> x;
auto h = x(key.getID());
```

Comment: Or via `auto x = std::hash<int>(); auto h = x(key.getID());` making it even more obvious that `x` in the second statement can be replaced by `std::hash<int>()`.

Comment: Thanks. So my error was assuming the hash definition as a template function instead than a type.

Comment: @Jepessen I guess so. `struct whatever{...};` means `whatever` is a type (or a template for a type, if preceded by `tempate <blah>`.

Comment: Yes I didn't see in the code that is a type. I've think that it was a templated function.

Comment: An alternative syntax is `std::hash<int>().operator()(key.getID())`, just for completeness.